# set button below google map in layout android

Tags: android

i want to set button below google map means button should be on bottom of screen and google map till just above the button,i cant set the height in dip of google map because then it would create problem on large screen or small screen...and if i set height of googlemap=wrap_content then not able to see map in my layout  then what should i do?my xml is below...

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
  android:clickable="true"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  android:id="@+id/map" 
 android:enabled="true"
 android:layout_below="@id/imv"
android:apiKey="xyz...."
/>
   <Button

     android:text="Map View" 
     android:id="@+id/button"

     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="30dip" 
      android:drawableTop="@drawable/icomapon"
     android:background="@drawable/navigationbar"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add below tag in `MapView`

```
android:layout_above="@+id/button"
```

Comment: actually i had made this ,after i saw ur solution...any way thanks...it works...chears..+1

Comment: @saurabhtrivedi which question post link

Comment: pls see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977916/how-to-deal-with-xml-parsing-for-invalid-character-use-in-url-for-getting-result