# how to deal with xml parsing for invalid character use in URL for getting result

Tags: android

i am able to do xml parsing for valid character but when i pass invalid character from my URL string then there no result found but when i pass that web service url from my browser then result is found.so i think problem in parsing for invalid character for doing sax xml parsing ,so how to overcome from this problem ,means how to deal with invalid character means in url **[http://www.arteonline.mobi/iphone/output.php?st=&ct=&type=Clínicas%20y%20Talleres&neigh=](http://www.arteonline.mobi/iphone/output.php?st=&ct=&type=Cl%C3%ADnicas%20y%20Talleres&neigh=)**
for type attribute i pass  type=Clínicas where 3rd character is not an English alphabet ,its in Spanish so how to deal with this Spanish

character. my code is below....

```
                  @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {
              try{ 
                  try {



                     String temp = "http://www.arteonline.mobi/iphone/output.php?st="+filter.stateselected+"&ct="+filter.cityselected+"&type="+filter.typeselected+"&neigh="+filter.neighbourselected+"";
                        //String temp = "http://www.arteonline.mobi/iphone/output.php?st=&ct=&type=Clínicas%20y%20Talleres&neigh=";

                      temp = temp.replaceAll(" " ,"%20");
                      //  temp= temp.replaceAll("í" ,"í");
                        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
                        Log.i("temp url..",temp.trim().toString());
                        URL sourceUrl = new URL(temp.trim());
                        XMLHandlerfiltersearch myXMLHandler = new XMLHandlerfiltersearch();
                        xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
                        xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

                    } 
                     catch (Exception e) {
                     System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
                    }
```

i replace space in my url if any by using  temp = temp.replaceAll(" " ,"%20");

but  i could not deal with Spanish character in type attribute in my web service url .pls help.....

also check for **type=Galerías**  when pass from web service url.. in this 6th charaacter is not valid..

Comment: Have you tried URL.encode with UTF-8

Comment: i write <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 in my .xml file

Comment: Have you looked at using `UrlQuerySanitizer` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/UrlQuerySanitizer.html ?

Comment: @seph i dont know how to use UrlQuerySanitizer for url can u explain it more ,i have seen ur given link also..

Comment: What is ur problem Spanish char in xml or in url?

Comment: hi ingsaurabh i think problem should be with Spanish character because  on parsing result is not found u can see it on ur browser by running it on ur system and also parse my given url using sax ....thanks for helping me...

Comment: @ingsaurabh problem in url when i pass spanish charracter value from thr Type attribute in url..pls see it...thanks

Comment: Thats why I said to use url.encode

Comment: how to use url.encode..?

Comment: @ingsaurabh done i will post my code soon...any way thanks alot u suggest me to go right way....

Comment: @ingsaurabh pls refer my new que.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005375/display-default-value-when-i-nothing-selected-from-spinner-array-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [URLEncoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html):

```
String stateselected= URLEncoder.encode(filter.stateselected, "UTF-8");
String cityselected = URLEncoder.encode(filter.cityselected, "UTF-8");
String typeselected= URLEncoder.encode(filter.typeselected, "UTF-8");
String neighbourselected= URLEncoder.encode(filter.neighbourselected, "UTF-8");
String temp = "http://www.arteonline.mobi/iphone/output.php?st="+stateselected+"&ct="+cityselected+"&type="+typeselected+"&neigh="+neighbourselected+"";
//String temp = "http://www.arteonline.mobi/iphone/output.php?st=&ct=&type=Clínicas%20y%20Talleres&neigh=";
```

if you have problems with the character encoding when parsing the XML you could set the encoding used by the parser:

```
InputSource is = new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream());
is.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
xr.parse(is);
```

Comment: may be is another encoding. I still don't know if your problem is with the call or with the parsing ... Do you receive the XML into your SAXHandler?